# Unable to send files between computers using Python socket programming

Tags: python, sockets, file-io

I wrote a socket programming code in Python. It is supposed to be able to send files between different computers. I tested my code on the same computer (ie. by sending files from 2 different folders) and it works. However, when I try to test the code by sending the files from my computer to my friend's computer, I keep getting this error:

```
 WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C://Users//Admin//Desktop//SharedFiles/*.*'
```

The error occurs when my Python program tried to access the `client_side_folder` variable as shown below:

```
client_side_folder = "C://Users//Admin//Desktop//SharedFiles"
```

I have also tried replacing the `client_side_folder` as "C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/SharedFiles" and "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\SharedFiles". But both still have the same error.

Does this error got to do with how Python deal with Windows address? If so, how come it works when I tried to send files from 1 folder to another folder in the same computer? Any ideas how I can solve this problem?

**EDIT:**

The code crashes where it hit the following code:

```
        def listOfFiles(directory): 
                list_dir = os.listdir(directory) 
                return list_dir
```

Comment: Is there a folder with that name on your friends computer? Please post the code where you do the send.

Comment: Yes, there is such a folder. The program crash before it reaches the sending part. I have pasted the code where it crash the whole program.

Comment: What does the function `numOfFileStatus()` look like?

Comment: It counts the number of elements returned from another function, filesToTransfer, which in turn call listofFiles function. I have updated how listOfFiles code looks like. That's where the code went wrong due to the directory.

Comment: I don't see any code for `filesToTransfer`. You need to post relevant code if you want us to help.

Comment: Just added the listOfFiles code.

Comment: Okay. I have posted it.

Comment: Please post all relevant code. I don't see what `filesToTransfer` does.

Comment: Okay. Nearly everything is up now.

Answer (score 0):

You might find it easier to handle paths in python, through the os.path module. For instance, if you want to access a file in the home directory of a user:

```
from os.path import expanduser, join

userhome = expanduser( '~' )
desktop = join( userhome, 'Desktop' )
shared_dir = join( desktop, 'SharedFiles' )
file_list = os.listdir( shared_dir )
```

This also implies that the user executing the script has access privileges to whatever path you're trying to access.

**addendum 1**:

Assuming you're using tcp sockets this a sample code for client and server:

server running on your friend's host:

```
import socket
serversocket = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM )
serversocket.bind( ( 'localhost', 13000 ) )
serversocket.listen(5) # 5 is the number of client connections that can be queued
while 1:
    #accept connections from outside
    (clientsocket, address) = serversocket.accept()
    # processing of the incoming connection
    ....
```

client running on your host:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM )
s.connect( ( 'friendshost', 13000 ) )
s.send( .... )
```

Comment: I couldn't get it to work on my computer. I am getting this error: "WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'Admin\\Desktop/SharedFiles/*.*'" now.

Comment: I updated the code snippet. Could you try that and tell me if it works for you ?

Comment: I'm getting this error now: WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'Admin\\Desktop\\SharedFiles/*.*'

Comment: can you paste the code you're trying to execute (that part of it that handles file access)?

Comment: The first function that caused the error is def listOfFiles(directory):
    list_dir = os.listdir(directory)
    return list_dir

Comment: what does os.path.exists() return when applied to the directory you're attempting to list ?

Comment: well it seems the way you're constructing the name of the directory, you're attempting to access is the problem. I'm only trying to confirm that.

Can you for instance add: print( directory ) before calling os.lisdir( directory ), just to see what is exactly is the name passed on ?

Comment: I did update the snippet of code in the post. could you try and see if it works ?

Comment: Now I see C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\SharedFiles but my friend did not receive any files from my side.

Comment: does that mean there is no "path not found" error anymore ? if yes, then the next step to troubleshoot is the networking part of your code.

Comment: I realised that now both of the address of the client and server is the same. That's why I couldn't send any files over. How do I make it different?

Comment: well, if I understood correctly you're trying to send a file to your friend's workstation through sockets. that implies a number of things:
1-you have a client and server implementation of your code running on both your machine and your friend's machine
2-you do know the ip address of your friend's machine. if you're both accessing the same Local Network, that should be easy. Otherwise if both of you is access the internet through his own WAN ip, there are steps to look at: does he or she have a firewall, does she have a local network, etc. That would impact the execution of your code

Comment: 1) Yes I have a client and server implementation on my friend and my workstation. 2) Yes I know his IP address and we are both behind the same NAT (ie. we are both using the same VPN) and the IP address that we used are the ones generated by the VPN.

Comment: OK, when you're talking about the same address for client and server, does that mean, the instance running on your machine ? If you're intending this code to be bidirectional (client sends and server receives files) it's normal that client and server are bound to the same address on the same host. The server should listen on its own port. and the client will open a remote connection to your friend's host.

Comment: My friend and I have different IP address. So what I did is ask him to run the code first so that he can act as the server and listen to the "client" requests which will come from me. Then I run the code and key in his IP address. Both of us are using the same port number at the start.

Comment: Erm. The code that is running on my side and my friend's side has to be the same. So I supposed I cannot have 2 different files for client and server?

Comment: The code might be the same. That is you can have your client and server bundled in the same module, but what should be running on your friend's host and what what should be running on your host cannot be the same. By definition any communication by tcp sockets involves a server socket and a client socket. And obviously the chunks of code that should be running at the same time to achieve a communication cannot be the same.

Answer (score 0):

**The Problem**

The code that is breaking is:

```
list_dir = os.listdir(directory)
```

This means the directory pointed to by `directory` does not exist in your local machine.

In your code, you have

```
client_files = listOfFiles(client_side)
server_files = listOfFiles(server_side)
```

which won't work.

You cannot use `os.listdir` to get the listing of a folder on a remote machine (friend's machine) without using something like `\\hostname\\path`.

When you are running the server and client on same machine, it works as both points to the local machine.

**Solution**

Method 1: Stop trying to get the listings of the remote machine and let the code running on that machine do it for you.

Method 2: Use remote access URL (shared folder or something) to access the details of the remote machine.

Comment: So does that mean that I need to put the IP address into the os.listdir? Something like os.listdir(FRIEND_IP+PATH)? Then for the path, it should be Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\SharedFiles?

Comment: Something like that, first try that from a command prompt to make sure you have proper access rights to the remote machine.

Comment: Can you explain more on the methods proposed? How do I check if I have the proper access rights to the remote machine?

Comment: Just type this in run prompt `\\1.2.3.4\Shared`. Note that you cannot directly use the directory path of the local machine. You have to make a shared folder and access that.

Comment: Okay. Now I keep getting this error: WindowsError: [Error 1326] Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password: u'//1.2.3.4/SharedFiles\\*.*'.

Comment: I found a way to fix the error. I have to turn off password protection on shared directories in our Control Panels. Is that another way which I use in order to get the list of files?

Comment: You should replace `1.2.3.4` with the hostname or IP address of the remote machine.

Comment: Yes I did. I already replace 1.2.3.4 as my friend's IP address.